# Injected 64 bit shellcode wont execute syscall

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm, shellcode

I am currently trying to inject code that will print helloworld into a vulnerable program. I have succeeded in injecting the code by storing it in one of the environment variables and overwriting the rip register to point to that code. 
Here is my assembly and op codes:

```
 0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   eb 17                   jmp    19 <stack_setup>

0000000000000002 <execute>:
   2:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
   5:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
   7:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
   a:   48 ff c7                inc    %rdi
   d:   5e                      pop    %rsi
   e:   b2 0f                   mov    $0xf,%dl
  10:   0f 05                   syscall 
  12:   b0 3c                   mov    $0x3c,%al
  14:   48 ff cf                dec    %rdi
  17:   0f 05                   syscall 

0000000000000019 <stack_setup>:
  19:   e8 e4 ff ff ff          callq  2 <execute>
  1e:   48                      rex.W
  1f:   65                      gs
  20:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  21:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  22:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  23:   2c 20                   sub    $0x20,%al
  25:   77 6f                   ja     96 <stack_setup+0x7d>
  27:   72 6c                   jb     95 <stack_setup+0x7c>
  29:   64 21 0a                and    %ecx,%fs:(%rdx)
  2c:   0d                      .byte 0xd
```

The opcodes after line 19 are for the instruction db "Hello, world!", 0x0a, 0x0d. After examining the execution of the instructions in lines x2-x10 with gdb, I have noticed that it properly prepared the arguments to print the string Hello, World. However, upon executing the syscall statement, nothing happens. Same is to be said for the instructions from line x12 - x17.

I have also tried to compile and link the assembly code to execute it independently and it works properly. In addition to that, I have compiled the vulnerable program with the options

```
  -fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

So that I can run code located in the stack. I have also disabled randomizing_va_space. I want to ask if there is something I did not do to allow me to successfully execute the code I injected?

Comment: You said your db "Hello world!", 0x0a, 0x0d put after line 19 so why you jump at line 19 in first line of your program ?

Comment: It is to set up the stack so that I can pop the address to the rsi register. Using call to a higher address might cause null bytes to be present. So, I jmp to a higher address, define the Hello world, then call to a lower address(since it is in two's complement there will be no null bytes), then pop the top of the stack containing the address of the string.

Comment: Programs, especially services do sometimes redirect/reopen their standard out; are you sure it's going where you think it is? Perhaps try using stderr instead; it's slightly less likely to be redirected to nowhere. Have you tried to run it on the stack with your own wrapper?

Comment: I coded the vulnerable program myself, so I am sure my where my standard out leads to. What bothers me is that nothing happens when I execute the syscall for the exit operation. It seems my commands are not reaching the kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason might be that the `write` syscall returns an error code. It could be for many reasons, but maybe `rdx` is not all zeros, so you should `xor %rdx, %rdx` before loading 15 there (actually you should load 14 only, for `"Hello, World!\n"`).

Anyway, the error from `write`  would be returned in `rax`, and be a negative number (`-errno`), thus when you do

```
mov    $0x3c,%al
dec    %rdi
syscall
```

That will be an invalid syscall, and `errno` 38 for `ENOSYS` will be returned.

The `exit` I got to work anyway by doing

```
xor    %rax, %rax 
mov    $0x3c,%al
syscall
```

I recommend that you run the program with `strace` and see from its output why exactly the `write` is failing.

---

Here's a version of shell code that works for me:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   eb 1d                   jmp    1f <stack_setup>

0000000000000002 <execute>:
   2:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
   5:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
   7:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
   a:   48 ff c7                inc    %rdi
   d:   5e                      pop    %rsi
   e:   48 31 d2                xor    %rdx,%rdx
  11:   b2 0e                   mov    $0xe,%dl
  13:   0f 05                   syscall 
  15:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  18:   b0 3c                   mov    $0x3c,%al
  1a:   48 ff cf                dec    %rdi
  1d:   0f 05                   syscall 

000000000000001f <stack_setup>:
  1f:   e8 de ff ff ff          callq  2 <execute>
  24:   48                      rex.W
  25:   65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  27:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  28:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  29:   2c 20                   sub    $0x20,%al
  2b:   57                      push   %rdi
  2c:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  2d:   72 6c                   jb     9b <stack_setup+0x7c>
  2f:   64 21 0a                and    %ecx,%fs:(%rdx)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it when I get home (I am currently at the office).

Comment: Accepting answer. You were right, I forgot to zero out the rdx register. I zeroed out the other registers, I dont know why I forgot about rdx.